# What is the "__.data" in python?

Tags: python, numpy

When I type

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
print(p.data)
s = p.data
print(s)
print(p)
```

The output is

```
<memory at 0x00000253683E8B88>
<memory at 0x00000253683E8B88>
[1. 2.]
```

What is difference between `p` and `p.data`?
In which case we use `p` or `p.data`?

Comment: `.data` just means "access the attribute named data for this object". Here is the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) for `numpy.ndarray` objects.

Comment: `p.data` is a `memoryview` object.

Comment: Unless you are doing something advanced, don't pay attention to the `data` attibute.  Its print in particular means nothing.